# fopen fwrite work but no file is created

Tags: visual-c++, fopen

below here is my very simple program.
If I run as guest (not administrator) and the file didn't exist at the moment of the execution, the program tells "OK" (that is, fopen and fwrite seem to work) but test.bin isn't created.
I expected fopen to return NULL but it did not. It correctly returns NULL if the file was previously created by the administrator and already existed but, if there isn't any file, it tells OK but the file isn't created.
Win 7 Professional, MSVC 6.0
Thanks
Tommaso

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("c:\\test.bin","w+b");

    if (fp==NULL) printf("Fopen returned NULL\n");
    else
    {
        if (fwrite("HELLO",5,1,fp)!=1) printf("Fwrite failed\n");
        else printf("OK\n");
    }
    if (fp) fclose(fp);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have UAC enabled on your system and your application does not have a manifest, the UAC virtualization system will redirect writes to certain protected locations.

This is for backwards compatibility - write permission is now denied for the system root but the virtualization system means that older software can continue to keep working rather than just failing outright.

If you add a manifest to your application then it will be seen as UAC aware and the virtualization will be disabled. Otherwise, you will probably find your file underneath `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\VirtualStore`.